# Concatenation of the variable and text in razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing the MVC application with razor syntax.

I am trying to concatnet the text and the id into the view.

I am using the below code...

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
  <input type="button" id= 'comment' @item.Id  class="deleteComment" value="Delete" />
 }
```

but when I inspect the elment in chrome, it looks like...

```
  <input type="button" id="comment" 134="" class="deleteComment" value="Delete">
```

check the comment text...

I am expecting like...

```
 <input type="button" id="comment134" class="deleteComment" value="Delete">
```

How to do this ?

> I found the solution myself.... Like this...

```
@{
var commentId = "Comment" + @item.Id;
}
<input type="button" id="@commentId" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" />
```

It works...

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <input type="button" id="comment@(item.Id)" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" />
}
```

Comment: No....It looks like  `<input type="button" id="comment@item.Id" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" />` in browser.

Comment: Oops need to put parenthesis around it.. see above!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <input type="button" id="comment-@item.Id" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
id="comment@(item.Id)"
```